# jmeter 2.11 - empty test plan

Tags: java, jmeter, test-plan

I am using Jmeter 2.11 with Java 1.7. The funny thing is I copy pasted a part of the code from another test plan which was probably written using an older version of Jmeter. The test plan ran fine but when I could not even open the test plan in the GUI mode. I get this exception.

I did notice that the cause-exception mentions the version to be 2.7 when I am using 2.11 probably because the ResultsCollector part was written using 2.7(I think) but then this should have failed way before. Why break all of a sudden?

Will I need to manually rewrite the ResultsCollector to make this go away? or is there a smarter way to make it go away?

Thanks.

```
2014/09/24 17:44:33 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: For input string: "
                            " : For input string: "
                            "
---- Debugging information ----
message             : For input string: "
                            "
cause-exception     : java.lang.NumberFormatException
cause-message       : For input string: "
                            "
class               : java.lang.Integer
required-type       : java.lang.Integer
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper
wrapped-converter   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.IntConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/ResultCollector/objProp/value/assertionsResultsToSave
line number         : 1087
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.ObjectProperty
converter-type[2]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[4]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[4]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
------------------------------- : For input string: "
                            " : For input string: "
                            "
---- Debugging information ----
message             : For input string: "
                            "
cause-exception     : java.lang.NumberFormatException
cause-message       : For input string: "
                            "
class               : java.lang.Integer
required-type       : java.lang.Integer
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper
wrapped-converter   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.IntConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/ResultCollector/objProp/value/assertionsResultsToSave
line number         : 1087
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.ObjectProperty
converter-type[2]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[4]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[4]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
message             : For input string: "
                            " : For input string: "
                            "
---- Debugging information ----
message             : For input string: "
                            "
cause-exception     : java.lang.NumberFormatException
cause-message       : For input string: "
                            "
class               : java.lang.Integer
required-type       : java.lang.Integer
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper
wrapped-converter   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.IntConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/ResultCollector/objProp/value/assertionsResultsToSave
line number         : 1087
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.ObjectProperty
converter-type[2]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[4]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[4]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : For input string: "
                            " : For input string: "
                            "
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter.unmarshal(SampleSaveConfigurationConverter.java:161)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : java.lang.Integer
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/ResultCollector/objProp/value/assertionsResultsToSave
line number         : 1087
version             : 2.7 r1342410
------------------------------- 
2014/09/24 17:44:33 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:93)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:747)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:725)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:216)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.testrunner.TestManager.executeSingleTest(TestManager.java:106)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.testrunner.TestManager.executeTests(TestManager.java:75)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.JMeterMojo.execute(JMeterMojo.java:41)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```